# How to derive <BS> in vim command mode?

Tags: vim

I came across the following while playing a [vimgolf challenge](http://www.vimgolf.com/challenges/53d93fc3768e280002124f23):

```
:%s/V/i?<BS>/g<CR>ii<C-C><C-C>ZZ
```

I think `<BS>` means "backspace" but when I press backspace in command line mode in the keyboard it simply deletes the "?" (I'm using a Linux Ubuntu machine with a Microsoft keyboard).  Does  mean backspace and if so, how do I notate that in command line mode?

Comment: this is just a "delete previous char" backspace. If you need to insert a special character in vim (eg a <BS>)you can type <C-V><BS>.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, `<BS>` means <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, see `:help key-notation`. But in command-line mode, using a literal backspace doesn't make sense (at least to me), because when typed, it just removes the `?`, and when inserted literally (using `<C-V><BS>`), it just inserts the four characters `< B S >`. Same with `<C-H>` = `^H`, which also stands for erase / backspace.

I think in this particular VimGolf challenge, `:%s/V/i/g` is what is meant, and this accomplishes the challenge. You simply got confused by a not-so-clever solution. Remember that not every golfer is a pro!

Comment: Thank you, that's a really great point about not everyone being a pro on that site.